# Spring Rest Template creating multipart form/data client working like a postman throws non convertable exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, httprequest, resttemplate

I want to turn this postman client with multipart/form-data header request to a spring template client.

[image: postmanClient]

Right now, I have a basic rest controller which works well.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MainConroller {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainConroller.class);
    @Autowired
    private MainService mainService;

    public MainConroller(MainService mainService) {
        this.mainService = mainService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/mails/send")
    public void send(
            @RequestParam("usertoken") String usertoken,
            @RequestParam("sendTo") String sendTo,
            @RequestParam("subject") String subject,
            @RequestParam("content") String content,
            @RequestParam(required = false, name = "files") List<MultipartFile> multipartFiles) {
        log.debug("{}, {}, {}, {}", usertoken, sendTo, subject, content);

        mainService.processMessage(usertoken, sendTo, subject, content, multipartFiles);

    }

}
```

I need to, however, create a rest client so I used a rest template, it right now looks like this:

```
ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(), new ResourceHttpMessageConverter(), new FormHttpMessageConverter()));
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate(converters);
    }
    File file = new File("*********");

            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

            MultiValueMap<String, Object> fileValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            fileValueMap.add(file.getName(), file);
            fileValueMap.add(file.getName(), file);
            fileValueMap.add(file.getName(), file);

            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> filesPart = new HttpEntity<>(fileValueMap, httpHeaders);

    //        String key values part

            MultiValueMap<String, String> stringPart = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            stringPart.add("usertoken", "test");
            stringPart.add("sendTo", "test");
            stringPart.add("subject", "test");
            stringPart.add("content", "test");

            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> objectPart = new HttpEntity<>(stringPart, httpHeaders);


            MultiValueMap<String, Object> multiPartRequest = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            multiPartRequest.add("ObjectPart", objectPart);
            multiPartRequest.add("FilesPart", filesPart);


            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(multiPartRequest, httpHeaders);

            String serverUrl = "****";

            restTemplate().postForEntity(serverUrl, requestEntity, String.class);
```

The problem is when I try to send the post request, It throws

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap] and content type [multipart/form-data]
```

**Update**

The solution on the client side is very simple, you can just send String values in the object values, which are going to be automatically casted to Strings via generics.

Also, the files cannot be send just as files but you have to create FileSystemResource instead, here is the complete code of the client side:

```
@Service
public class RestTemplatePost {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    public void prepareMessage() throws Exception {


        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        MultiValueMap<String, Object> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        form.add("usertoken", "test");
        form.add("sendTo", "test");
        form.add("subject", "test");
        form.add("content", "test");
        form.add("files", getTestFile());
        form.add("files", getTestFile());

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(form, httpHeaders);

        String serverUrl = "******";

        restTemplate().postForEntity(serverUrl, requestEntity, String.class);


    }

    public static Resource getTestFile() throws IOException {
    Path testFile = Paths.get("C****");
    System.out.println("Creating and Uploading Test File: " + testFile);
    Files.write(testFile, "Hello World !!, This is a test file.".getBytes());
    return new FileSystemResource(testFile.toFile());
}

}
```

Comment: Use one `MultiValueMap` instead of multiple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are making things too complex. You should use a single map to hold the form values not a map of maps. Next to that Spring Boot already provides a `RestTemplate` so you don't need to configure your own again.

```
File file = new File("*********");

HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

MultiValueMap<String, Object> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
form.add("files", file);
form.add("files", file);
form.add("files", file);

form.add("usertoken", "test");
form.add("sendTo", "test");
form.add("subject", "test");
form.add("content", "test");

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(form, httpHeaders);

String serverUrl = "****";

restTemplate().postForEntity(serverUrl, requestEntity, String.class);
```

The `RestTemplate` (or actually the `FormHttpMessageConverter`) will transform it into a correct request.

Comment: Your solution works. However, the files were never sent in the request, so I needed to create FileSystemResource instead, I have updated my post.

Comment: I was suspecting that as there is no converter for a file.

Comment: I have realized just now that when I try to send the actual file and not only the FileSystemResource, they never arrive at the server side. What can i do about that ?

Answer (score 7):

The default RestTemplate constructor does not include any message converters, you need to add it. For example, you can do it like:

```
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new 
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(parts, requestHeaders);

RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

return restTemplate.postForObject(apiURI, requestEntity, String.class);
```

Comment: It does include default converters. It detects them based on the available libraries on your classpath.

Comment: My understanding based on the documentation: `Objects passed to and returned from these methods are converted to and from HTTP messages by HttpMessageConverter instances. Converters for the main mime types are registered by default, but you can also write your own converter and register it via the messageConverters bean property.` and based on this : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest list only MultiValueMap<String, String> is included.

Comment: That is wrong. Just take one look a [the constructor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.java#L139) of `RestTemplate`... Also you clearly state, as the first sentence, that no message converters are included... That is just plain wrong...

Comment: I might be wrong, in my pervious comment the quote is from the RestTemplate constructor.

Comment: In your comment, not in your answer. But it isn't only for mime types also form handling etc. is registered. Also the comment also indicates that there are message converters registered by default where you state there aren't. Nonetheless you shouldn't, generally, need to add/remove converters. Especially not with Spring boot.